# Jmeter distributed testing master as 2 clients

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-5.0, distributed-testing

i want to perform distributed testing on a couple of slaves machines with different purposes and use the same master for that.
the problem is that it's not working good together. for example: i have 3 slaves who are responsible to execute test plan X and i have 3 slaves who are responsible to execute test Y.

when i invoke just test X or just test Y the master and the slaves works fine, but when i try to invoke test X and then test Y the later get close immediately.

i guess that it's because the rmi port is used by the previous test.

is there any when to configure the properties file so i can execute both test X and test Y?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot run more than one test at a time on a given slave.

If your slave machines are powerful enough you can launch 2 different slaves processes on different ports like:

1. Start slave process #1 on port 1111:

   ```
   jmeter -Jserver.rmi.port=1111 -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=10.20.30.40 -s
   ```
2. Start slave process #2 on port 2222:

   ```
   jmeter -Jserver.rmi.port=2222 -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=10.20.30.40 -s
   ```
3. Now you can specify on master on which slave you want to execute the current test like:

   - `jmeter -Jremote_hosts=10.20.30.40:1111 -r -n -t test1.jmx` will start `test1` on first slave instance
   - `jmeter -Jremote_hosts=10.20.30.40:2222 -r -n -t test2.jmx` will start `test2` on second slave instance

     and these may go in parallel

More information:

- [Remote hosts and RMI configuration](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#remote)
- [How to Perform Distributed Testing in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-perform-distributed-testing-in-jmeter)
- [Overriding Properties Via The Command Line](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#override)

Comment: i am not talking about multiple tests on slaves, but multiple clients on the master. each slave will run 1 test